# Lookup and Sum simulated data

Tags: r, loops, lookup

I have some portfolios and simulated stock data and are looking to figure out a way of summing them together.  Was trying to do this in excel with vlookups but was crashing from memory loss so I am trying to use R.  Here is some sample data:

```
     > p1 = c("a", "b", "c")
     > p2 = c("d", "e", "f")
     >p3 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
     > s1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
     > s1 = c(2,3,4,5,6,7)
     > p = rbind(p1, p2)
     > s = cbind(s1, s2)
     > colnames(p)= c("Stock1", "Stock2", "Stock3")
     > rownames(s) = p3

         > p
           Stock1 Stock2 Stock3
        p1 "a"    "b"    "c"   
        p2 "d"    "e"    "f"

        > s
          s1 s2
        a  1  2
        b  2  3
        c  3  4
        d  4  5
        e  5  6
        f  6  7
```

I am looking to get output like this

```
 p1   "a" "b" "c"  6  9
 p2   "d" "e" "f" 15  18
```

Was hoping to create a matrix like this

```
i=1
stocksim = null
while (i < ncol(s)) {
simsum = sum(s[p$stock1,i],s[p$stock2,i],s[p$stock3,i])
stocksim = cbind(stocksim,simsum)
i=i+1
}
```

Then cbind this to my p data frame.

I am getting this error, `Error in p$stock1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Please let me know your thoughts.  Thanks,

Comment: This works great for this small set, how can I scale it for larger portfolios, and 6000 total portfolios and 1000 simulations?

Comment: The below code works also for a larger amount of p and s, as long as they are in the same format as your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
p<-cbind(as.data.frame(p,stringsAsFactors=F),t(sapply(1:nrow(p),function(x){colSums(s[p[x,],])})))

p
#    Stock1 Stock2 Stock3 s1 s2
# p1      a      b      c  6  9
# p2      d      e      f 15 18
```

What it does is the following :

- given that you want to have some character values and some numerical values you have to use a dataframe
- you take the sums of the columns of a subset of s (with the rows that interest you)
- you append those do the original p

In detail : `as.data.frame(p,stringsAsFactors=F)` converts p to a dataframe and keeps the character values as strings, not as factors. `t(sapply(1:nrow(p),function(x){colSums(s[p[x,],])}))` is the function which for each row of p (`1:nrow(p)`) takes the sums of the columns (`colSums`) of a subset of s (`s[p[x,],]`). The output should be `t`ransposed. Then you append (`cbind`) the original p and the new values.

Comment: This works great for the sample data set, but when I expand it to my larger data set I get the follow error.  Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'

Comment: Could you cut my code in 4 parts and see which one causes an error ? The parts are `sapply(1:nrow(p),function(x){colSums(s[p[x,],])})`, `t()` of the previous part, `as.data.frame(p,stringsAsFactors=F)` and the `cbind`

Comment: That is what I tried, it is the sapply part causing the error. Both inputs are data frames.  It seems to come from the s[p[x,],]

Comment: Does `colSums(s[p[1,],])` work ? If yes, try repalcing the 1 by any number between 1 and the number of rows of p. Could you also edit your question by posting s and p using `dput` (use `head` if they are too big) ?

Comment: Are the inputs dataframes or matrix ? In your examples they are matrix but in your comment you say they are dataframes. P is probably a dataframe, that is the root of the problem

Comment: @JB17: Try `cbind(as.data.frame(p,stringsAsFactors=F),t(sapply(1:nrow(p),function(x){colSums(s[(as.character(p[x,])),])})))`, it should fix the problem of p as a dataframe

Comment: I can but issue with using head is that you wont see observations needed for the calculation.  But I will post it

Comment: @JB17: did you check if p was a dataframe and if the code in the comment work ?

Comment: The code in the comment works.  Both datasets were dataframes.

Comment: @JB17 : good to know. If p is already a dataframe you can remove the `as.data.frame` in the function.